# Adding a down limit switch on a Vevor hoist

Tags: circuit-design, switches

[image: hoist electric diagram]

I need to add a down limit switch on a hoist, and I'm wondering how can I modify the circuit to allow the second limit switch. I included the electric diagram of the circuit.

Comment: what behavior do you want the limit switch to initiate?

Comment: I installed a hoist for an indoor elevator. It comes with a built-in upper limit switch and I want to add a lower limit switch on the circuit. There is one capacitor in the junction box, and one in the remote.

Comment: I want the elevator stops when it reaches the ground floor.

Comment: please add that info to your question

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmuqxe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Rewired control circuit.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9Q64x.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Effective circuit when going up and going down.*

Comment: I rewired the  circuit as per your diagram and it’s now working well with the down limit switch. But I do now have a buzzing noise (electrical charge) when the switch stops the motor up and down.

Comment: I also have a second capacitor in the junction box connected between the up and down wires going to the motor. 
Could it be the cause?

Comment: The wiring in that diagram doesn't show the capacitor in the position of C1 in my Figure 1.